# Get name of index in foreach

Tags: php

```
$array = array('first' => array(1, 3), 'second' => array(5,6), 'third' => array(8,4));

foreach($array as $a){
  echo "key = " . key($a) . "\n";
};
```

How can i get name of index from this array?
i would like receive:

```
key = first
key = second
key = third
```

but this return me in each case key = 0. Why? How can i get name of index?

[codepad](http://codepad.org/ONTG82VJ)

Comment: `foreach ($array as $index => $a)`. Please **[read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**, this is practically the first thing it explains. I see you are new here; you should know that you are expected to show some effort of your own when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
  echo "key = " . $key . "\n";
};
```

if you want to print the value instead:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
   echo "value = " . $val . "\n";
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the other syntax of [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo "Key: ".$key;
}
```